# Find an equation of the tangent line to the curve $y = x\cos(x)$ at the point $(\pi, -\pi)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I concluded that the equation is
$$(y + \pi) = (\cos(x) + x-\sin(x)) (x - \pi)$$

1) Is this correct so far?  Wolfram doesn't seem to process this correctly.

2) How would I expand this to get it in $y$-intercept form? I know I can plug $\pi$ into my derivative, but i'm not sure what to make of plugging $x$ into it. I feel like it wouldn't be correct, or it would be correct but it would be so verbose the data would be unusable.

Comment: You did not evaluate the derivative correctly, but you are close.

Comment: If you want to type trigonometric expressions, be sure to type for instance \cos, not cos.  cos gives you italicized cos while \cos gives you the not-italicized cos.  \cos is $\cos$ whereas cos is $cos$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your derivative, which we need for slope, is close, but $y'$ should be  $$y' =\underbrace{(1)}_{\frac d{dx}(x)}\cdot(\cos x) + (x)\underbrace{( -\sin x)}_{\frac d{dx}( \cos x)}= \cos x -x\sin x$$  Now, for slope itself, we evaluate $y'(\pi) = \cos (\pi) - \pi\sin(\pi) = -1 - 0 = -1$.

That gives you the equation of the line: $$y+\pi = -(x -\pi)$$

To get the slope-intercept form, simply distribute the negative on the right, and subtract $\pi$ from each side to isolate $y$: $$y + \pi = -x+ \pi \iff y = -x$$

Comment: why is $x$  negative in the derivative? I understand why $sin$ would be. I'll show you how I set my derivative up when I solve it, tell me what I did wrong:       

     $x' cos + x cos'$

     $x' = 1 and cos' = -sin$

     Therefore:

    $1 * cos + x - sin$

     $cos + x - sin$

Comment: That is because you use product rule

Comment: Yes, we have $y'= \cos x +(x)\times(-\sin x) = \cos x -x\sin x$. You forgot that we are multiplying $x$ and $-\sin x$.

Comment: Ahh, I understand completely now. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome! Glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

Your gradient of the tangent line is not correct.

**Step 1.** Differentiate $y=x\cos x$. $y'=\cos x-x\sin x$.

**Step 2.** Find the gradient of the tangent line by putting $x=\pi$ into $y'$; thus $m=-1$.

**Step 3.** Write the equation of the line in the form $y-y_0=m(x-x_0)$; thus $y+\pi=-1(x-\pi)$ (or $y=-x$)

To find the $y$-intercept, you put $x=0$, so $A(0,0)$ is your $y$-intercept.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that the product rule is

$$\dfrac{d}{dx}[f(x)g(x)] = f'(x)g(x) + f(x)g'(x)$$

Let $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = \cos(x)$.  Then, $f'(x) = 1$ and $g'(x) = -\sin(x)$.  So the derivative of $y = x\cos(x)$ is
$$y' = \cos(x) - x\sin(x)$$

Then, at $x = \pi$
$$y'(\pi) = \cos(\pi) - \pi \cdot \sin(\pi) = -1 - \pi \cdot 0 = -1$$

Thus, the equation of the tangent line is
$$y + \pi = -(x - \pi)$$